# How to check for empty textbox

Tags: c#, tryparse

On a site I found the `TryParse` method (how to check if there is a empty textbox in C#) but I don't know how to use it.

```
int outputValue=0;
bool isNumber=false;
isNumber=int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out outputValue); 
if(!isNumber)
{
 MessageBox.Show("Type numbers in the textboxes");
}
else
{
// some code
}
```

and how can i solve this for 1+ number of textboxes

Comment: which bit is confusing you? (btw, the code you have provided isn't checking if the textbox is empty)

Comment: `String.IsNullOrEmpty` is used to check whether a text is null or empty.

Comment: This doesn't check for an empty check box. It will let you know if the text in the text box is an integer or not.

Comment: solve what? `TryParse` will return `false` if it cannot parse the value into a `Int` (for example if the Text is empty) - so whatever is in your else branch gets executed ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to check empty for all text box control in your page .Try [IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
 foreach (Control child in this.Controls)
    {
        TextBox textBox = child as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Text box can't be empty");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is "this.Controls"? For me it throws an error saying that "(pagename) does not contain a definition for Controls"

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use the TryParse function. The TryParse function in your example above will try to convert the text of textBox1 into the value outputValue.

If it succeeds, the boolean isNumber becomes true and the parameter outputValue get's the value of the Textbox converted to an int.

If it fails, the 'IsNumber' property will stay false, and the property outputValue is never changed.

Basiclly, if you need to check if a textbox is empty you can use:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox2.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox3.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox4.Text)) 
{
    // At least 1 textbox is empty.
} 
else
{
    // All the textboxes are filled in.
}
```

Comment: how  can i solve this for all textboxes in go, so for example i need 4 texboxes. Do i need write the code for all texoxes separately?
And works this for strings only? i need only int/float/double variables.

Comment: But if they need to be filled in all four, you can use a if statement with multiple clauses. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Complexity is right. just want to add that there is also string.IsNullOrWhitespace(). Typically whitespace is considered as empty :)

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to complete this task

```
1. string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text)  
2. textbox1.Text =    string.empty();  
3. textbox1.Text = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
if(textBox1.Text.length==0) {
  //do something
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below menioned code

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text))
{
   int outputValue=0;
   bool isNumber=false;
   isNumber=int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out outputValue); 
   if(!isNumber)
     {
       MessageBox.Show("Type numbers in the textboxes");
     }
    else
    {
      // some code
    }
}
```

Comment: that was typo changed it :)