# How to ignore emptytextboxes in C#

Tags: c#, casting

Just learning C# so maybe this is an easy fix but ive tried alot of different approaches but end up with the same result.

I have 8 textboxes where the user should enter a number, and then after pressing the result button these textboxes will then be multiplied with some numbers and then added together.

However if i leave one textbox blank, this results in a date time error.

How could i solve this ?

In the code below m only using 2 of the textboxes, but there will be alot more

thanks

small code:

```
public void Multiply() {

    int heroT1Might = 100;
    int inputT120;
    int inputT150;

    int chest20 = 20;
    int chest50 = 50;
    int chest100 = 100;
    int chest200 = 200;
    int chest300 = 300;
    int chest500 = 500;
    int chest1K = 1000;
    int chest10K = 10000;

    inputT120 = int.TryParse(textBox20.Text);
    inputT150 = int.TryParse(textBox50.Text);
    long result = (inputT120 * chest20 * heroT1Might) + (inputT150 * chest50 * heroT1Might);

    resultLabel.Text = result.ToString();

}
```

Comment: `if(textbox.Text != "")`? Please do some research yourself this is everywhere on the internet

Comment: @EpicKip Or even better: if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(textbox.Text))

Comment: @oopbase That's what I use myself, but this guy does not know what he is doing. Maybe we should keep it simple :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for empty textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24546604/how-to-check-for-empty-textbox)

Comment: well, anyway to ignore the fact that its empty and do the calculations of the rest them?

Comment: Make a variable with a default value (0 maybe...) And don't change it if its empty how hard is this

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for an `empty` `strings` like the following snippet:

```
int i;
if (!int.TryParse(textBox20, out i)) i = 0;
```

Comment: He does not even know what tryparse does... Don't encourage this

Comment: @EpicKip Okay will be take it under consideration for future answers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
        int heroT1Might = 100;
        int chest20 = 20;
        int chest50 = 50;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox20.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox50.Text))
        {
            // At least one is empty
            return;
        }

        if(!int.TryParse(textBox20.Text) || !int.TryParse(textBox50.Text))
        {
            // At least one is not an integer
            return;
        }

        var inputT120 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox20.Text);
        var inputT150 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox50.Text);
        long result = (inputT120 * chest20 * heroT1Might) + (inputT150 * chest50 * heroT1Might);

        resultLabel.Text = result.ToString();
```

Or you can do like this or something :

```
        int heroT1Might = 100;
        int chest20 = 20;
        int chest50 = 50;

        var inputT120 = int.TryParse(textBox20.Text) ? Convert.ToInt32(textBox20.Text) : 0;
        var inputT150 = int.TryParse(textBox20.Text) ? Convert.ToInt32(textBox50.Text) : 0;
        resultLabel.Text = ((inputT120 * chest20 * heroT1Might) + (inputT150 * chest50 * heroT1Might)).ToString();
```